# What hardware do I need to upload code onto a PIC 10F200?

Tags: pic

I apologize if this is a dumb question or answered elsewhere but I could not find a definitive answer.  What hardware do I need to upload code onto a PIC 10F200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're purchasing a new programmer I'd recommend the [PICkit 3 In-Circuit Debugger](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en538340&redirects=pickit3) or the ICD 3 if your budget runs to it and you need the extra features. While the PICkit 2 will program the device the following table from Microchip shows it as no longer recommended for new designs.

It has support for some of the newer chips and has better MPLAB X support. Scrolling through the devices you mentioned in MPLAB X shows all of them as fully supported. I also believe the new price is around the same (it was cheaper at one place I checked):

[image: Microchip's Debugging and Emulation Product Line]

Answer (score 2):

Microchip's Pickit 2 or 3, PICSTART Plus, or MPLAB PM3

Personally I'd recommend the [PICkit 3](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en538340&redirects=pickit3) or [PICkit 2](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en023805)

You can find answers to questions like this one on the microcontroller's datasheet

[The following was taken out of the datasheet for the PIC10F200/202/204/206](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41239D.pdf)

[image]

Comment: I would recommend the Pickit 3 instead of the pickit 2. It's better than the pickit 2, if you decide to use some of the newer pics you won't be able to program them using the pickit 2. I use the pickit 3 for almost everything, it's really good.

Comment: @scrafy Agree, it was my original answer but then I had a hard time finding the compatible devices list of PICkit 3 to confirm it. PICkit series are great for debugging too.